# IndexOutOfBound Exception in ArrayList set(position,object) method RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I am using arraylist in `Recyclerview` adapter and I am using increment button after I am pressing this I have update the quantity in same position but I am facing `IndexOutOfException` kindly help me to resolve this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ItemsModel model=itemsModelList.get(position);
    confirmItemModel=new ArrayList<ConfirmItemModel>();

    holder.text_name.setText(model.getName());
    holder.text_count.setText(model.getCount());
    holder.btn_inc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int qty=Integer.valueOf((String) holder.txt_qty.getText());

            if(qty==0){
                qty++;
                holder.txt_qty.setText(String.valueOf(qty));
                confirmItemModel.add(new ConfirmItemModel(model.getName(),model.getCount(),String.valueOf(qty)));
            }else if(qty>0){
                qty++;
                holder.txt_qty.setText(String.valueOf(qty));
                confirmItemModel.set(position,new ConfirmItemModel(model.getName(),model.getCount(),String.valueOf(qty)));

            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

Calling `set` means replacing `element` which is already added in the `position` with the new `element`.

More info: [ArrayList - Set Method](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/arraylist/arraylist_set.php)

But, in `RecyclerView`'s `onBindHolder()` it will throw an error because `onBindViewHolder` fills the new data and does not replace any position.

Hence, You cannot call `set` in `onBindViewHolder()`.

For example, if the user enters `qty = 5` and the `arraylist` has only 3 elements, then obviously it will not replace a position 5 because it is not filled yet.

If you want to increase the quantity of any item, please make sure the `position` is not empty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you can tell me exactly what to do I can update in my answer.. I mean what is the requirement.?